# Is it safe to set NetworkActivityIndicatorVisible value in secondary thread?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I wonder if AppDelegate is thread safe? I currently have an operation running networking tasks on the secondary thread, when the task begins, I would like to set `NetworkActivityIndicatorVisible` to `YES`, and when the task is done, set it to `NO`. Do I have to always call it in the main thread, or I can do it in the current run loop thread?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

In general, UIKit is not thread safe.  While you may be able to "get away" with some things, you should always do UIKit stuff on the main thread.  There are a few, well documented, exceptions.

The pattern for doing this from a background thread is simple.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Put any code you want to execute in the main thread here.
});
```

The code inside the block you pass to dispatch_async will be scheduled to run in the main run loop.

Comment: Yeah, in general, you are right. But I wonder since NetworkActivityIndicatorVisible is just a boolean value, it should be thread safe. But I also think that this value controls the indicator to start/stop animating. So It must run in the main thread. So I don't know if it got handled automatically in the main thread. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Better safe than sorry - call it on the main thread unless the UIApplication docs *explicitly* say it's safe to call from other threads.

Comment: How do you know it's "just a boolean?"  Have you looked at the UIKit source code?  Can you be sure it will not change?  You are messaging an instance of UIApplication, which is part of UIKit, whose documentation says not to do anything but a few specially noted things from outside the main thread.  Thus, you should not do it.  Can you get away with it?  Probably, but why even code that way?  What possible benefit can be derived from writing code that intentionally violates the documented usage principles of the API?  I'm sure there are cases for such use, but this is surely not one of them.

Comment: oh wow thanks, I was previously creating main thread methods, but this is SO much easier.